# Using MVC dropdown list how to edit form and show the data in dropdown and previously selected item in dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and displaying categories in drop down list. Foam allow user to edit the previously added data. So when i perform update action all the other data that user enter can easily displayed but who to display the selected category value from drop down list and show that valve in drop down?

Controller

```
using (var catRepo = new BusinessLayer.Repostories.CategoryRepository())
{
  ViewBag.VBCategoryList = new SelectList(catRepo.GetAllCategories(),"CategoryId","Name");
}
```

View

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", ViewBag.VBCategoryList as SelectList)
```

Comment: Does you model include a property named `CategoryId`? If so, set its value so that it matches one of the option values - it will then be selected.

Comment: do you please enhance your answer ? how to set the value it is dynamic because every time value will be changed

Comment: You need to show your model that your using in the view and the controller methods

Comment: OK why do you rate negative to my question ? i am new so i doesn't mean to do that

Comment: I didn't down vote ,but I will if you don't show the relative code (the model and the controller methods)

Comment: i found my answer from Mr.Razack Raz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model should contains CategoryId

```
public int CategoryId{get;set;}
```

Your Edit Action will be similar to below code

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   using (var catRepo = new BusinessLayer.Repostories.CategoryRepository())
   {
      var itemToEdit=catRep.GetItemById(id);// replace your method
      ViewBag.VBCategoryList = new  SelectList(catRepo.GetAllCategories(),"CategoryId","Name",itemToEdit.CategoryId);
   }
   return View(itemEdit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use javascript to do this.you have just write your javascript code in document.ready(function()

document.getElementById("your dropdown id").value = '@Model.yourDropdownValue';